# Retrieve update date of HERE Maps API

Tags: here-api

We are developing a WebGIS with AngularJS and JavaScript that use HERE Maps API.
We want to show the date of acquisition or update of the satellite maps published through Here Maps.

Is there any way to recover this information?

Answer (score 0):

Geocoder API does give information about the mapVersionRelease. The following GET request uses the parameter locationattributes=mapReference to retrieve information about the currently used map version.

Please refer https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/dev_guide/topics/example-geocode-mapreference.html and https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/dev_guide/topics/resource-params-additional.html